# Output the nth 'boring' number

Tags: code-golf, sequence

There are 9 main types of numbers, if you categorise them by the properties of their factors. Many numbers fall into at least one of these categories, but a few don't. The categories are as follows:

- Prime - no integer divisors other than itself and one
- Primitive abundant - A number \$n\$ whose factors (excluding \$n\$) sum to more than \$n\$, **but** for any factor \$f\$ of \$n\$, the sum of the factors of \$f\$ sum to *less than* \$f\$
- Highly abundant - A number \$n\$ whose factors (*including* \$n\$) sum to more than that of any previous number
- Superabundant - A number \$n\$, such that the sum of the factors of \$n\$ (including \$n\$) divided by \$n\$ is greater than the sum of factors of \$g\$ over \$g\$ for any value \$0<g<n\$
- Highly composite - A number \$n\$ which has more factors than \$g\$, where \$g\$ is any number such that \$0<g<n\$
- Largely composite - same as highly composite, but \$n\$ can have also have *equally as many* factors as \$g\$
- Perfect - A number that is exactly equal to the sum of its factors (excluding itself)
- Semiperfect - A number that can be made by summing up two or more of its factors (excluding itself)
- Weird - A number \$n\$ that is not semiperfect, but which's divisors sum to more than \$n\$.

A so-called 'boring number' is any positive, non-zero integer which does not fit into any of these categories.

Your job is to create the shortest possible program which can, given a positive number \$n\$, outputs the \$n\$th boring number.

*Note: I am aware there are more categories, but I wanted to avoid using mutually exclusive ones (such as deficient and abundant), because then every number would fall into one of them.*

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply; standard I/O methods apply.
- All inputs will be positive, non-zero integers, a single output is expected.
- `n` can be 0- or 1- indexed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

## Tests

The first 20 boring number are:

`9, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50`

Comment: Do the factors of \$n\$ include \$1\$ or no? Just making sure

Comment: @ValueInk - Yep.

Comment: If I understand right, a number that is neither perfect, semiperfect, nor weird has to be deficient, which makes a lot of the other conditions redundant.

Comment: Why isn't 16 a boring number?

Comment: I think I got it, 16 is highly abundant as the number itself should be included in the sum and `1+2+4+8+16 = 31 > 28 = 1+2+3+4+6+12`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>226 220</s>  209 bytes

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to @HermanL*

Input is 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(x,n=m=c=1,D=k=>k?n%k?D(k-1):[k,...D(k-1)]:[],S=a=>s=eval(a.join`+`))=>(S(a=D(n))>m?m=s:0)|(s=a.length)<3|(s<c?0:c=s)|a.reduce((a,x,i)=>i?[...a,...a.map(y=>[...y,x])]:a,[[]]).some(a=>S(a)>=n)||--x?f(x,n+1):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/RioMwEEV/xYcuzGAMyrIvrpO8@Ad9FMEhjV2rJsV0i6X2292UhYHLHYZ77lz4zsEsw/WWOX@ye09xYBWOZjJUiJpGUqN2H6OuYcwKLJtRSCn/TVs2rTgSkwpk7zwBy4sfXJd2iKTgCEw1OEQ165lCmeMGgVhO1p1vP1h9RlsZnZeGAm4sF3v6NRaAxSqGGDDoJqL4zWM58xUepN6bh1jbyGbRNG2LMvjZRpKKOFTkcNuybNX9@4s0FnZ77xdwCSXFd@KSKvnKo6YpJsa74CcrJ3@GjuHwdC@MZ4dnH0u/Otz/AA)

Optimizations are based on the following properties:

- All primitive abundant numbers are either semiperfect or weird.
- All highly composite numbers are largely composite.
- All superabundant numbers are highly abundant.

Comment: -9 bytes by inlining the `D` function (as it is only used once) [TIO](https://tio.run/##JY9hi4MwDIb/Sg92kGAtenBfvKV@2T/YRxEMXd2c2g67G4653@5VDgIhL@HJkys/OJipu91T5092bSkWzNLRSIZyeSQmHcg@eABWV9@5JmkQScMRmOBAPem@dJ99eYA@zbGoeqmU@h/qoqoRHKIey5FCkeHywdVXvQAEYjVYd75fcG/KrDAUcGE12dOvsQAsZ9nFK11ZRRpvSFYj3@BJekuecq4jnmVV1TWq4EcbdXR0Qk0OlyVN57Ld/kiik1tbP4ETJPIf4cRefGexJwkK413wg1WDP0PDsHu5N8a13auN2u8G1z8)

Comment: @HermanL Thanks! (Inlining `D` doesn't actually change anything, but your more concise rewrite of the function definitely does.)

Comment: Another 2 bytes saved: [TIO](https://tio.run/##JY/RioMwEEV/xYcuzGAMyrIvrpO8@Ad9FMEhjV2rJsV0i6X2292UhYHLHYZ77lz4zsEsw/WWOX@ye09xYBWOZjJUiJpGUqN2H6OuYcwKLJtRSCn/TVs2rTgSkwpk7zwBy4sfXJd2iKTgCEw1OEQ165lCmeMGgVhO1p1vP1h9RlsZnZeGAm4sF3v6NRaAxSqGGDDoJqL4zWM58xUepN6bh1jbyGbRNG2LMvjZRpKKOFTkcNuybNX9@4s0FnZ77xdwCSXFd@KSKvnKo6YpJsa74CcrJ3@GjuHwdC@MZ4dnH0u/Otz/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>43</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> <s>33</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒpyLRÑOć‹PyÑ¨©æOyå®Oy›O_}Iè
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Mr.Xcoder*.
-12 bytes thanks to *@Grimy* (of which -5 are because ["*Highly composite numbers higher than 6 are also abundant numbers*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number#Related_sequences), and -4  because "*'The sum of N's divisors is greater than N' is equivalent to 'The sum of some subset of N's divisors is greater than N'*").

0-indexed.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqScHlMUsORT8SH4oC5UHnDkcKow6ZPeUDDoE9ffUnDqP//OQ) or [output the first \$n\$ values of the sequence](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqScHlMUsORT8SH4oC5UHnDkcKow6ZPeUDDoE9ffUnCo///MjU).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞           # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ          # Filter it by, leaving only the integers `y` which are truthy for:
  p         #  1) Check if `y` is a prime
  yL        #  Create a list in the range [1, `y`]
    R       #  Reverse the list to range [`y`, 1]
     Ñ      #  Get the divisors of each integer
      O     #  Sum the inner lists together
       ć    #  Extract the head; pop and push remainder-list and head
        ‹P  #  2) Check if each value in the remainder-list is smaller than the head
  yÑ        #  Get the divisors of `y`
    ¨       #  Remove the last item (`y` itself)
     æ      #  Powerset; get all possible combinations of these divisors
            #  (this includes both an empty list and all divisors of `y`)
      O     #  Sum each inner combination-list
       y@à  #  3) Check if any sum is larger than or equal to `y`
  O_        #  And only leave the integers in the filter which are falsey for all checks
}Iè         # After the filter: Index the input-integer into the filtered list
```

1) covers the check for Prime
2) covers the checks for Highly Abundant, Superabundant, Largely composite and Highly composite
3) covers the checks for Perfect, Semiperfect, Weird, and Primitive Abundant

Comment: @Grimy Thanks. Not sure how I missed `yå`.. Such an obvious golf. But thanks for the `2FyLÑRNmOć‹P}`. I had the feeling I could somehow combine some parts, but wasn't sure how. And yes, I indeed noticed I still used the `X` from the old version in the explanation.

Comment: @Grimy Oh, very nice optimizations!

Comment: `ć‹P` can be `Zk_` (same byte-count but easier to type).

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 208 bytes

Input is 1-indexed.

```
interface a{static void main(String[]a){int i=0,n=0,x=1,z=1,j,u,f,b;for(;n<new Integer(a[0]);n+=f>=i?0:1/++b){for(i+=j=u=f=b=1;++j<i;)if(i%j<1){f+=j;b=0;u++;}x=f>x--?b=f:x;z=u>=z?b=u:z;}System.out.print(i);}}
```

in readable form:

```
interface a
{
    static void main(String[]a)
    {
        int i=0,n=0,x=0,z=0,j,u,f,b;
        for(;n<new Integer(a[0]);n+=f>=i?0:1/++b)   //checks perfect, semiperfect, weird, and p. abundant numbers
        {
            for(i+=j=u=f=b=1;++j<i;)if(i%j<1){f+=j;b=0;u++;}    //checks prime numbers
            x=f>x--?b=f:x;              //checks highly abundant and superabundant numbers
            z=u>=z?b=u:z;               //checks largely and highly composite numbers
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest `f<i?1/++b:0` instead of `f>=i?0:1/++b` and `f+=i%j<1?j+=b=0*u++:0;` instead of `if(i%j<1){f+=j;b=0;u++;}` and `u>z` instead of `u>=z`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
Æd,Æs)Ṫ_$<Ø.S;Æṣ<$;Ẓ¬$Ạµ#}1Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//w4ZkLMOGcynhuapfJDzDmC5TO8OG4bmjPCQ74bqSwqwk4bqgwrUjfTHhuar///8yMA)

A full program taking a single argument N and outputting the 1-indexed boring number.

Takes advantages of the optimisations noted in the description of @Arnauld’s answer, but not based on the JavaScript code.

#### Explanation

```
Æd,Æs)Ṫ_$<Ø.S;Æṣ<$;Ẓ¬$Ạµ#}1Ṫ

                       µ#}1  | Run the following for each number from 1 increasing in steps of 1 until we have as many true values as indicated by the argument, then return the numbers for which it was true:
     )                       | - For each number from 1 up to the currently tested number:
Æd                           |   - Count of divisors
  ,                          |   - Paired with:
   Æs                        |     - Sum of divisors
      Ṫ_$                    | - Tail (divisor count and sum for current number) minus divisor count and sum for all smaller numbers
         <Ø.                 | - Check if each [divisor count difference, divisor sum difference] < [0, 1]
            S                | - Sum (will sum the checks of divisor count difference and divisor sum difference separatelt)
             ;               | - Concatenate to:
              Æṣ<$           |   - Whether proper divisor sum less than current number
                  ;          | - Concatenate to:
                   Ẓ¬$       |   - Whether number is not prime
                      Ạ      | - All of these (only true for boring numbers)
                           Ṫ | Finally, take the tail (the requested boring number)
```

In contrast to many of the Jelly code explanations I’ve written, this almost goes from left-to-right!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 155 bytes

```python
n=input();k=D=N=0
while n:k+=1;L=[d for d in range(1,k+1)if k%d<1];S=sum(L);W=len(L);K=S-k;x=K<2or S>D or W>=N or K>=k;n-=1-x;N=max(W,N);D=max(D,S)
print k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCoMwEIDh3ae4pZCgQiOdep5TNiWLg0PpIKg1RE@xSu3Tp9rp/5Z//q79xIn3TJbnbRUSHWkydA0@vR1a4LsLSWFBjwa6aYEGLMNS86sVKnKhkrYDd2lS9cSS3tsoCokVDS2fyKmMHe6Up8mxlpmGI1VG5myekUOOScU7GhrrXVSRkaj/1FEpg3mxvILz/vYD) [first n entries](https://tio.run/##PY@xjoJAFEV7vuIVbsJEII6dPh4V2mCwoKAwFkTGZTL6IDBG3NVvR7Cwuqe5Off@ddVwKiyE4Wa/hQis6mzQPAYmzc3NugINxZTSwrlX@qKA12ZOEnd0KOFct1CCZmgL/lWu9MxcCn0G81OG8ogZdberuxOY00XxBAllvsGeknA5VrMohjHyiNIpk4gMsk/S7zGla9G7uZcKjD8Ye5lwmlazBTOMSx1nkutJ/i@DYCZfCOpU1TDT8ITmYaual98zg1y9AQ)